Is "bet" only used by vulgar people?
My cousin says "bet" is only used by vulgar people, and that "wager" is used by gentlemen. I disagree. We're talking about risking money on an outcome.
I wonder if the fine people here can adjudicate this controversy, since English is not our first language.
The actual quote comes from Stephen King, in his short story "The Ledge" (from his book Night Shift):

“What's the bet?”


He looked genuinely pained. “Wager, Mr. Norris, wager. Gentlemen make wagers. Vulgarians place bets.”

I say that a writer can make his characters say anything; my cousin says it's real and one should not say "bet" but "wager" in polite company.

Given that Cressner is a wealthy and cruel criminal, how could he value a gentleman? Isn't the distinction gentleman / vulgar a matter of opinion? Isn't Cressner's admonishment part of his ploy to manipulate Norris?

It's not that "gentlemen" don't use the word "bet" but that people who haven't read much and who didn't take a college-prep course of study in high school in the US would be very unlikely to use  wager as a verb and somewhat unlikely to use it as a noun, preferring bet over it.  bet is an everyday word whereas wager is part of a literate person's vocabulary.

Stephen King is humorously pointing out the rarefied idiolects (hifalutin' language) some old-fashioned people think needs preserving. Though perhaps more people might disapprove of actually betting at all, especially in some environments. I can't imagine some people saying "I had/placed a bet/wager on City to win", or any paraphrase thereof.

Stephen King made a joke and you can bet your **** that your cousin didn’t get it. “Wager” is just pretentious.

Saying "I'll wager that Jenkins will be there" is old-fashioned, but saying "I bet Jenkins is there" is idiomatic. (Risking money is hypothetical in this example but the OP does not show the intended usage.)
Google Ngram Viewer shows that the use of bet has been steadily increasing for 200 years.


How to make sure your chart does not include other meanings of "bet" beyond the meaning "wager"?

@GEdgar what other meaning of 'bet' do you have in mind?

Yes, we're referring to risking money on an outcome.

I can't remember the last time I heard sth like "I'll wager on Pegasus in the Grand National." But even if you aren't betting with money, there is always something at stake – your credibility, for example.

The question is about how vulgar the usage of bet and wager is, if it is.

@Gio if it isn't slang, then it isn't vulgar.

'If it isn't slang, then it isn't vulgar' doesn't hold; crude use of language can use a scientific register. // But the 1-grams doubtless pretty accurately reflect the decline in the use of 'wager'. I'd expect an 'old-fashioned' or even 'archaic' caveat in a dictionary nowadays.

I don't think I've ever heard a modern croupier say "place your wagers", they all say "place your bets". It might have been considered vulgar at one time, now it's commonplace.
